# Is there a str.split equivalent for lists in Python?

Tags: python, string, list

If I have a string, I can split it up around whitespace with the `str.split` method:

```
"hello world!".split()
```

returns

```
['hello', 'world!']
```

If I have a list like

```
['hey', 1, None, 2.0, 'string', 'another string', None, 3.0]
```

Is there a split method that will split around `None` and give me

```
[['hey', 1], [2.0, 'string', 'another string'], [3.0]]
```

If there is no built-in method, what would be the most Pythonic/elegant way to do it?

Comment: You did not specify the behavior for `[None, 1, None, None, 2, None]`, which I assume should yield `[[],[1],[],[2],[]]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A concise solution can be produced using itertools:

```
groups = []
for k,g in itertools.groupby(input_list, lambda x: x is not None):
    if k:
        groups.append(list(g))
```

Comment: Change your lambda to `lambda x: x is not None` and you can simplify your `if` statement to `if k` (since `k` will be true only if the group is not a group of `None`s).  And nice answer - +1!

Comment: or: `groups = [list(g) for k, g in itertools.groupby(input_list, lambda x: x is not None if k]`

Answer (score 3):

import `itertools.groupby`, then:

```
list(list(g) for k,g in groupby(inputList, lambda x: x!=None) if k)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is not a built-in way to do this. Here's one possible implementation:

```
def split_list_by_none(a_list):
    result = []
    current_set = []
    for item in a_list:
        if item is None:
            result.append(current_set)
            current_set = []
        else:
            current_set.append(item)
    result.append(current_set)
    return result
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Practicality beats purity
final = []
row = []
for el in the_list:
    if el is None:
        if row:
            final.append(row)
        row = []
        continue
    row.append(el)
```

Comment: @cmh - Basically, if you need to do something right now, sometimes the simplest way is what you need - avoid digging for hours to find the most "Pythonic" way to do something.  But if you *find* a better way to do it (as your answer most certainly is), then by all means, use it :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
def splitNone(toSplit:[]):
    try:
        first = toSplit.index(None)
        yield toSplit[:first]
        for x in splitNone(toSplit[first+1:]):
            yield x
    except ValueError:
        yield toSplit
```

```
>>> list(splitNone(['hey', 1, None, 2.0, 'string', 'another string', None, 3.0]))
[['hey', 1], [2.0, 'string', 'another string'], [3.0]]
```