# Removing punctuations and spaces in a string without using regex

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, punctuation

I used import `string` and `string.punctuation` but I realized I still have `'…'` after conducting `string.split()`. I also get `''`, which I don't know why I would get it after doing `strip(`). As far as I understand, `strip()` removes the peripheral spaces, so if I have spaces between a string it would not matter:

```
>>> s = 'a dog    barks    meow!   @  … '
>>> s.strip()
'a dog    barks    meow!   @  …'


>>> import string
>>> k = []
>>> for item in s.split():
...  k.append(item.strip(string.punctuation))
... 
>>> k
['a', 'dog', 'barks', 'meow', '', '…']
```

I would like to get rid of `'', '…'`, the final output I'd like is `['a', 'dog', 'barks', 'meow']`.

I would like to refrain from using regex, but if that's the only solution I will consider it .. for now I'm more interested in solving this without resorting to regex.

Comment: Can I ask the reason why you don't want to use Regex?

Comment: What's the output you want to get?

Comment: @Aran-Fey ['a', 'dog', 'barks', 'meow']

Comment: @MichaelH. if item == '…' or '': ?

Comment: `…` is not an ASCII punctuation character, so as such, its not included in `string.punctuation`. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html?highlight=punctuation#string.punctuation

Answer (score 2):

You can remove punctuation by retaining only alphanumeric characters and spaces:

```
s = 'a dog    barks    meow!   @  …'
print(''.join(c for c in s if c.isalnum() or c.isspace()).split())
```

This outputs:

```
['a', 'dog', 'barks', 'meow']
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following:

```
s = 'a dog    barks    Meow!   @  … '



import string
p = string.punctuation+'…'
k = []
for item in s.split():
    k.append(item.strip(p).lower())


k = [x for x in k if x]
```

Answer (score 0):

building on the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12023775/is-there-a-str-split-equivalent-for-lists-in-python):

```
import itertools

k = []
for ok, grp in itertools.groupby(s, lambda c: c.isalnum()):
    if ok:
        k.append(''.join(list(grp)))
```

or the same as a one-liner (except for the import):

```
k = [''.join(list(grp)) for ok, grp in itertools.groupby(s, lambda c: c.isalnum()) if ok]
```

[`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) scans the string `s` as a list of characters, grouping them (`grp`) by the value (`ok`) of the lambda expression. The `if ok` filters out the groups not matching the lambda. The groups are iterators that have to be converted to a list of characters and then joined to get back the words.

The meaning of [`isalnum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalnum) is essentially “is alphanumeric”. Depending on your use case, you might prefer [`isalpha()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isalpha). In both cases, for this input:

```
s = 'a 狗    barks    meow!   @  …'
```

the output is

```
['a', '狗', 'barks', 'meow']
```

(For experts: this reminds us of the problem that not in all languages words are separated by non-word characters - [e.g.](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%90%89%E5%A4%9A%C2%B7%E8%8C%83%E7%BD%97%E8%8B%8F%E5%A7%86))